# standard environment naming, staging, production

Tags: naming-conventions, environment, production, staging

I am a native Dutch speaker, and we refer to the different environments for production, staging etc. as "OTAP"

- Ontwikkeling - Development
- Test - Testing
- Acceptatie - Acceptance / Staging
- Productie - Production.

I would like to know if there is a similar acronym/standard naming scheme in English? It is hard to google, as I do not know the proper words to search for (otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also a native Dutch speaker. OTAP is the Dutch translation of [DTAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production) (development, test, acceptance, production). Although there is not much concencus regarding naming schemes I currently use the following naming (much like what you suggested) for web development:

development.domain.tld (for local development, though domain.dev is used a lot as well)

test.domain.tld (for testing)

acceptance.domain.tld (for customer acceptance)

domain.tld (live site)

the acceptance site is usually misused as a staging environment as well.

When it was not related to web applications or web sites we used to refer to the type of test (SAT: site acceptance test, FAT: factory acceptance test and sometimes IAT: integration stage if more companies work on one project).